# Not allowed to load local resource: I got this error in chrome console

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-models

I am creating a Django application. While placing a background picture, I got this error in the console:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/UsersThripura%20saiPycharmProjectspythonProjectecomuploadsproducts%E0%AB%8ER_Aspire_7.jpeg
```

My CSS code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #6a6f8c;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  background-image: url('C:\Users\Thripura sai\PycharmProjects\pythonProjectecom\uploads\products\ACER_Aspire_7.jpeg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font: 600 16px/18px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
}

.one-edge-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 2px -5px rgb(246, 245, 245);
}

.display-8 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: I think it is happening because of '///C:' part. can you try with two or one slashes?

Comment: You can't serve a _user-local_ file to the user - that would be a serious security flaw. The image needs to be served using your django root as domain and placed somewhere in the django path.